# Problem with plotting graphs in 1 row using plot method from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, subplot

Suppose I want to plot 3 graphs in 1 row: dependencies `cnt` from other 3 features.

**Code:**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 10))
for idx, feature in enumerate(min_regressors):
    df_shuffled.plot(feature, "cnt", subplots=True, kind="scatter", ax= axes[0, idx])
plt.show()
```

**Error message:**

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-697-e15bcbeccfad> in <module>()
      2 fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 10))
      3 for idx, feature in enumerate(min_regressors):
----> 4     df_shuffled.plot(feature, "cnt", subplots=True, kind="scatter", ax= axes[0, idx])
      5 plt.show()

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

But everything is ok when I'm plotting in (2,2) dimension:

**Code:**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 10))
for idx, feature in enumerate(min_regressors):
    df_shuffled.plot(feature, "cnt", subplots=True, kind="scatter", ax= axes[idx / 2, idx % 2])
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

I'm using `python 2.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to pandas. The index error you see comes from `ax= axes[0, idx]`. This is because you have a single row. `[0, idx]` would work when you have more than one row.

For just one row, you can skip the first index and use

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 10))
for idx, feature in enumerate(min_regressors):
    df_shuffled.plot(feature, "cnt", subplots=True, kind="scatter", ax= axes[idx])
plt.show()
```

*As a recap*

**Correct**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 3))
axes[0].plot([1,2], [1,2])
```

**Incorrect**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 3))
axes[0, 0].plot([1,2], [1,2])
```

**Correct**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 3))
axes[0,0].plot([1,2], [1,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

For you to learn and understand what is happening, I suggest you check the size of `axes` in both of these situations. You will see that when either `nrows` or `ncols` is 1, the axes variable will be 1-dimensional, and otherwise it'll be 2 dimensional.

You cannot index a 1-dimensional object the way you are doing (`ax= axes[0, idx]`).

What you can do is use numpy's [atleast_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) to make the axes 2D.

Alternatively, a better solution would be to iterate over the features and axes directly:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 10))
for ax, feature in zip(axes, min_regressors):
    df_shuffled.plot(feature, "cnt", subplots=True, kind="scatter", ax=ax)
plt.show()
```