# matplotlib indexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to use subplots to plot multiple graphs. The idea is to have something similar to the code in the subplot example section on https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html

The snippet of my code is given below

```
revenues = np.array(base_stock.getSeriesfromData(profit_loss,'Sales',-3))
profit_after_tax = np.array(base_stock.getSeriesfromData(profit_loss,'Net profit',-3))
fig,axis = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True) 
axis[0,1].plot(base_stock.time_axis,revenues,'-o')
axis[1,1].plot(base_stock.time_axis,profit_after_tax,'-x')
```

When I try to run the code the following error pops up

IndexError: too many indices for array

I printed out the inputs I give the plot() call. They are as follows

```
 base stock time is  [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 revenues is  [2592.45 6696.76 8238.2 14766.6 25298.4 30414.4 34660.7 
 37216.3 42375.5,56293.3]
 profit after tax is  [176.25 242.77 390.8 259.6 444.5 765 862.5 1292.3 1554.3 1597]
 shape of revenues is  (10,)
 shape of base_stock is  (10,)
 shape of profit after tax is  (10,)
 type of revenues is  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
 type of profit after tax is  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
 type of base_stock time is  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here.  Would be great if someone can give me some insight on this issue in case I have missed something.

The entire error is shown below with traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('F:/Investment/new_fundamental_analysis.py', wdir='F:/Investment')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\anoop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 688, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\anoop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "F:/Investment/new_fundamental_analysis.py", line 104, in
>   
>       axis[0,0].plot(base_stock.time_axis,revenues,'-o')
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: `axis[0,1]` should be `axis[0,0]`, the same for `1,1`. Although I think it won't fix the problem. Can you show the full error message? Especially in which line it occures.

Comment: @dyukha edited the question to add the traceback of the error

Comment: @UserA: I answered similar question yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495582/problem-with-plotting-graphs-in-1-row-using-plot-method-from-pandas). Read my answer and try to adapt it for your case. Your problem is with column index, the answer yesterday had a problem with row index

Comment: @UserA: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: @Bazingaa: thank you for the help. Was able to plot the graphs.